# how to authenticate angular post call from nodejs based on stdout and stderr

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, node.js, angular-fullstack

I am using angular-fullstack generator to create web app. Front end designed using angularjs and server side using nodejs. I have written a python function to know if a host is a linux host or not, which is invoked through nodejs and writes to a file 'This is a valid host' in case of valid linux host. If the host is linux host I want to redirect to different page.
My angular code:

```
$scope.sendlogin = function () { 
            console.log("inside click");

            var posting = $http({
                method: 'POST',

                url: '/login',
                data: $scope.data,
                processData: false
            })
            posting.success(function (response) {

                $location.path("/vprobe");
            });

             }
```

My node code:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
/* Handling the AngularJS post request and storing in a file*/
var fs = require("fs");
console.log(req.body);
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

 var file = 'login.json'
 var obj = req.body;

 jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, function (err) {
 console.error(err)
 })

// invoking python child process 
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var arg = 'python  checkvalidity.py'
exec(arg, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
console.log('exec error: ' + error);
res.send(stdout);
 });

 });
```

But above code is not working correctly. For both stdout and stderr its redirecting to page. The stdout reads a file which has a content 'This is a valid host'. How to redirect only in case of stdout , and display a error in case of a error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use res.sendStatus(500) in your nodeJs code if (!stdout ) and catch it in your angular controllers with .error(function(response))

Comment: Not exactly what you told , but somewhat similar code worked for me . Thanks a lot

Comment: So what was the problem

Comment: stdout was redirecting to page for both success and error. So i just checked if (stdout contains some symbol that only comes for success ) to execute the success part and otherwise redirect to error part.